# Best match in C# to Java ReentrantLock and Condition?

Tags: c#, java, multithreading

Another cross-language question: can someone tell me what C# Threading constructs best match the Java ReentrantLock and Condition classes?  ReentrantLock has lockInterruptibly() and unlock() methods, while Condition has signal() and await() methods.  It is this combination that I would like to be able to preserve in the C# code - or something similar... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the static [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) class. I allows for [blocking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx) and [non-blocking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter.aspx) mutex acquisition, as well as [condition variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_variable) operations. (They call them [Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx), [PulseAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulseall.aspx) and [Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait.aspx) rather than signal and await).

Comment: Seems to be working for me!  Thanks!  Another question: does Monitor provide a counterpart to Java isHeldByCurrentThread() ?

Comment: No, you could extend Monitor and keep a reference to the Thread which last successfully called Enter or TryEnter. The current thread can be accessed using Thread.CurrentThread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread.aspx

Comment: @BenS, what the C# equivalent be of Java `taskEnded.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` where `taskEnded` is of type `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition`. `Monitor.Wait` doesn't seem to match.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**: I don't know these Java classes, I'm taking a stab in the dark here.

In C#, you have a `lock` statement (I think this is something like Java's `synchronized` statement) which can lock on any object. I suppose using that statement, or `Monitor.Enter(obj)` and `Monitor.Exit(obj)` would be a bit like ReentrantLock.

There are two class called `ManualResetEvent` and `AutoResetEvent`. These classes have a `Wait` method, and a `Set` method, which I suppose is like Condition's signal and await. The difference between these two classes is that a `ManualResetEvent` stays set (no longer blocking anyone) and must be `Reset`. And `AutoResetEvent` is - like its name suggests - reset automatically.

Comment: Cannot use lock in async statement and Monitor methods needs to be called from synchronized thread.. the point of Java's ReentrantLock is to make those issues go away.

Comment: Seeing as async methods didn't exist in either C# or Java when this question was asked, I think that's hardly the point of ReentrantLock, or at least not the point the asker was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) class would also be worth looking into. This is similar to [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) in Java.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the similarity. But MSDN recommends using [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) over `ReaderWriterLock`.